# When I use IonReorder and try to save the order of an array in state, I'm given a different seemingly random order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-react-starter-telztw?file=pages%2FHome.js

When I try and reorder and save it in state the order in the component snaps to a different order.  I expected it to stay in the order I put it in.  How do I keep it in the right order?

It acts normal when you get rid of the `setItems` line, but I want to save it in state.

Comment: issue it with your deepcopy or items. `[...items]` not creating deep copy.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib  Thanks I just tried `const reorderedItems = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(items))` and it still doesn't work